# Excel Formula Value Error with If Statement and Range Row Property

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet with some UDF's. First time trying anything complex in excel and I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly. The following formula returns a #VALUE error.

```
=IF(INDEX(findRed(C3:L11), 1, 1)=3:3,3500000+35000000*0.1, "")
```

findRed is a UDF to look in the Range given for cells with red background color. What I want to do is determine if any of the cells returned by the findRed function are in the 3rd row of the workbook. The math on the end are numbers I intend to use, but I intend to make a fairly large nested IF OR AND statement with the Range returned by findRed and I can't even get the first part to work. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: findRed()

```
Public Function findRed(myRange As Range) As Range
Dim redRange As Range, cell As Range
Application.Volatile
For Each cell In myRange
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
    If redRange Is Nothing Then
        Set redRange = cell
    Else
        Set redRange = Application.Union(redRange, cell)
    End If
End If
Next cell
Set findRed = redRange
End Function
```

Comment: **Post the findRed() code.**

Comment: posted findRed() function

Answer (score 0):

Your UDF `findRed` potentially returns a multi area range (if there are more than one discontinuous red cell in the input range) or a `#VALUE` error if there are no red cells.

Your problem is how you process this return range with the rest of your `=IF(INDEX(...))` formula

An alternative test you can use is

```
IFERROR(ROW(findRed(C3:L11) 3:3)>0,FALSE)
```

This will return `TRUE` if any cell in the intersection of your specified range (`C3:L11`) and row 3 are red, otherwise `FALSE`.

You can then embed this in your `IF AND OR` formula

Comment: @stev0 I see you acepted then unaccepted this (thats fine, you can accept or not as you see fit) Is there some other problem with this answer you need help with?